# iPhone - Conversion between NSDate - NSString - NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I'm using following code to get NSDate, convert it to NSString and then back t NSDate.

```
NSDateFormatter* dtFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dtFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY"];

NSDate* dt = [NSDate date];
NSString* strDate = [dtFormatter stringFromDate:dt];
NSLog(@"First = %@",strDate);
NSDate* dt2 = [dtFormatter dateFromString:strDate];
NSString* strDate2 = [dtFormatter stringFromDate:dt2];
NSLog(@"Second = %@",strDate2);
```

But the output I'm getting is different:

```
2011-02-12 08:17:21.851 SF Calculation[16297:207] First = 02/12/2011
2011-02-12 08:17:21.852 SF Calculation[16297:207] Second = 12/26/2010
```

Why is it different when converting NSDate to NSString and back from NSString to NSDate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of :

```
[dtFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY"];
```

use:

```
[dtFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
```

Comment: +1 - link to spec - http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Date_Format_Patterns